# How to detect Region Enter/Exit for multiple beacons using AltBeacon android-beacon-library?

Tags: android, ibeacon

I am working with iBeacons and using the AltBeacon library.

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers()
             .add(new BeaconParser()
             .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

I would like my Android app to detect and generate an event when beacons enter and exit visibility.
This works just fine fine with a single beacon using the library using methods.

```
public void **didEnterRegion**(Region region)
```

and

```
public void **didExitRegion**(Region region)
```

My problem is when multiple beacons are visible at the same time.
I am trying to maintain an array with all beacons visible. 
I want to generate an event each time a beacon enters and exits.
The event should identify the beacon that generated the event by it's unique Identifier.
My beacons are uniquely identifiable using the `beacon.getIdentifiers()` or (UUID, Major and Minor)

The problem is that the `didExitRegion` method does not get executed until all beacons exit the region.

Can anyone think of a simple way for me to achieve my goals using AltBeacon library?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask you how do you test if a beacon exit the region? I need to write a program like this one you are writing... perhaps do you move your beacon to another place and check if the `didExitRegion` method was run? Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Two options:

1. Set up a different region to match only each individual beacon, specifying all their identifiers, and monitor for each.  You will get a different entry and exit callback for each region.

   ```
   Region region1 = new Region("myIdentifier1", Identifier.parse("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"), Identifier.parse("1"), Identifier.parse("1"));        
   Region region2 = new Region("myIdentifier2", Identifier.parse("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"), Identifier.parse("1"), Identifier.parse("2"));   

   beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region1);
   beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region2);
   ```
2. Enable ranging, and put code in the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` callback to track individual beacons.  You can use a `java.util.HashMap` to keep track of all beacons that are visible (with a timestamp for the latest time each was seen), and then if you haven't seen a beacon in, say, five seconds, you can remove the beacon from the `HashMap` and  execute your exit logic for that beacon.

Option 1 is great for a small number of beacons where you know their identifiers up front.  Option 2 is more involved, but better for a large number of beacons or if you do not know their identifiers in advance.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but what is myIdentifier1 and what should it be set to?

Comment: It is just a unique string to identify the region.  You can use the same string to stop monitoring.  The string can be any value you want as long as it is different than any other region you have constructed.

Comment: does this means I can't monitor for proximityUUID or proximity+major only? others library allow it (iOS works like that)

Comment: I misunderstood the API, the identifiers (id1, id2 and id3) are actually uuid, major and minor, if I pass null it allow them to be anything. But the order matters... why not calling them uuid, major and minor? major and minor are integer uuid is a string uuid. Why wrapping them in an Integer class?

Comment: Sorry, I understand that the names are a bit vague.  Two reasons for this:  (1) the library is used for several beacon types and not just iBeacons.  The terms uuid, major and minor are iBeacon-specific.  (2) The library is open source so we avoid using any terms specific to a proprietary technology like iBeacon.  They are wrapped in an Identifier class to hide the complexity associated with dealing with multi-byte identifiers that vary in length (with iBeacon a UUID is 16 bytes and major and minor are two bytes).  Usually you don't need to think about it.

Comment: What else do I need, to call startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion from other Activity ?

Answer (score 1):

/***************This Code for estimote Beacons *****************/

```
private  final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("beaconall", null, null, null);

private BeaconManager beaconManager;

public  onCreate()
{

    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady()
        {
            Log.d("Lalit", "Beacon service Ready");

            beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
            beaconManager.startMonitoring(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
        }
    });
    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {

            int index = beacons.size();
            // UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("");
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Beacon SelectedBeacon = beacons.get(index-1);

                Log.d("Lalit", "Beacon Id :- " + SelectedBeacon.getProximityUUID());
                Log.d("Lalit", "Beacon major :- " + SelectedBeacon.getMajor());
                Log.d("Lalit", "Beacon miner :- " + SelectedBeacon.getMinor());
                Log.d("Lalit", "Beacon total :- " + beacons.size());
                Log.d("Lalit","Distance :- "+ getDistance(SelectedBeacon.getRssi(),SelectedBeacon.getMeasuredPower()));
            }

        }
    });

    beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new BeaconManager.MonitoringListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date entertime = calendar.getTime();
            Log.d("Lalit", "Region Enter :- " + entertime);
            Log.d("List", "Region  UUID id :- " + region.getProximityUUID());
        }

        @Override
        public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date entertime = calendar.getTime();
            Log.d("Lalit", "Region exit :- " + entertime);
            Log.d("List", "Region  UUID id :- " + region.getProximityUUID());
        }
    });
}
```